# windows 7 graphics problems, it looks like XP

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have windows 7 ultimate installed in my PC, but recently, the theme looks like XP, and I found that all Aero themes are disabled.

I tried to restore the system, but it shows an error message "the system restore does not appear to be functionning correctly on this system"

Comment: What happens when you choose a different theme?

Comment: I can't use Aero themes or windows 7 theme

Comment: So what happens when you try? Do you get an error message?

Comment: What happens when you try and restore? Do you get an error message?

Comment: You need to give more information. Otherwise we cannot answer ... just saying "it doesn't work" is not enough information.

Comment: Do you have a graphics driver installed? `Start` -> `dxdiag` in the search box -> `Enter` -> `Display`. Please include a screenshot from this screen.

Comment: When I try to change the theme, all Aero themes are disabled

Comment: open cmd.exe as admin, run **winsat formal**, now look if you can select an aero theme

Comment: "the instance name passed was not recognized as valid by a WMI data provider"

Comment: please share the file "C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\winsat.log" this include the log of the failed winsat call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following steps :

1. open the windows task manager
2. show the services
3. show the themes service properties
4. set the startup type to Automatic and start the service

Comment: Did you solve the problem and this was your solution, or is this additional explanation for your question of what you did?

Comment: Yes, I solved the Aero themes problem with this solution.